# Code adds an unnecessary "3" between 0x and the number when multiplying and converting it to hex

Tags: c++, hex

I have written a tool for implementing cryptography. Its purpose is to take a string of numbers and a multiplicator, multiply the numbers and print them in hexadecimal representation with a leading 0x and a trailing ",":

As mentioned, the actual number has a leading 3 after the 0x. I suppose that there is a software bug—maybe it comes from converting ASCII characters?

I compile it with `cl.exe hex_mult.cpp /EHsc /favor:INTEL64 /Ox` if that helps.

I have already rewritten my code several times, but I don't really know what I could try here.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "hexconvert.hpp"
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;
    int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    string str;
    long int mult = 1;
    cout << "Please enter a string of numbers:" << endl;
    getline(cin, str);
    cout << "Please enter the multiplicator:" << endl;
    cin >> mult;
    cout << "The numbers multiplied by " << mult << ", represented as hex values:" << endl;
    for(int C = 0; C<str.length(); C++) {
        unsigned long long int x = str[C]*mult;
        cout << int_hex(x) << ", ";
 }
    cout << endl;
    system("pause>nul");
    return 0;
    }

hexconvert.hpp:
    #include "sstream"
    #include "iostream"
    #include "string"

    std::string int_hex(unsigned long long int dec) {

    std::stringstream stream; //New string stream
    stream << std::hex << dec; //Convert to hex before adding to stream
    std::string hexstr(stream.str()); //Convert back to string

    for(size_t counter = 0; counter <= hexstr.length(); counter++) { 
     //Convert all lowercase to uppercase
         if(hexstr[counter]>=97 && hexstr[counter]<=122) { //Only 
     process if the value has the id of a character
             hexstr[counter] = toupper(hexstr[counter]); 
         }
    }
    return hexstr;
    }
```

I expect `123, 2` to output `0x1, 0x2, 0x3`, but the actual output is `0x31, 0x32, 0x33`.

Comment: The hexadecimal value of ASCII `'1'` is 0x31.

Comment: Just a suggestion for making code more readable and simpler:  Where the comparison of the string characters are made to between 97 and 122, instead write what it means:  `if (hexstr[counter]>='a' && hexstr[counter]<='z')`.  There is also a c runtime library function available from `#include <ctype.h>`:  `if (islower(hexstr[counter]))`.

Comment: Could you run a test case and post its entire output here?

Comment: @wallyk -- even better, use `std::islapha` instead of hard-coding non-portable assumptions. There are character sets that have characters between the values of `'a'` and `'z'` that are not alphabetic characters.